# Exiting a while loop on java

Tags: java, while-loop

I am trying to create a program where I use the getInt method to make sure that the user enters a positive number. I have this so far

```
public class Binary {
  public static void main(String [ ] args) {
   Scanner CONSOLE = new Scanner(System.in); 
   int decimal=getInt(CONSOLE, "Enter a positive integer: ");

   } 

  public static int getInt(Scanner CONSOLE, String prompt) {                      
   System.out.print(prompt);  
   while (!CONSOLE.hasNextInt()) {
    CONSOLE.next();                          
    System.out.println("Not an integer; try again.");                          
    System.out.println(prompt);
   }
   int posInt=CONSOLE.nextInt();
   while (posInt <= 0) {
    System.out.println("Not a positive integer; try again.");
    CONSOLE.next();
    System.out.println(prompt);
   }  
  return CONSOLE.nextInt();
  }  

}
```

The issue occurs that when the user does enter a positive number it still disregards the input and asks the user to enter a positive integer again. I guess I'm just not exiting the loop correctly but I'm not sure how.

Comment: The line `return CONSOLE.nextInt();` seems to be prompting the user for yet another integer even if they've already entered one.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is `return CONSOLE.nextInt();`

At the end of your method, you are calling `CONSOLE.nextInt()` which asks for input once more.

Return `posInt`, and you'll be fine.

Best of luck, HTH

Comment: I had tried doing that and it continued to give me the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Like the others said you can return `posInt` and you should be fine.
But i have some recommendations for your `getInt` method:

```
 public static int getInt(Scanner CONSOLE, String prompt) {
    //initialize vars
    boolean valid = false;
    int posInt = 0;
    //while the input is not valid, loop over the evaluation
    while(!valid){
        System.out.print(prompt);
        if (!CONSOLE.hasNextInt()) {
            CONSOLE.next();
            System.out.println("Not an integer; try again.");
            //"continue" stops the loop here and starts it from the beginning
            continue;
        }
        posInt=CONSOLE.nextInt();
        if (posInt > 0) {
            //valid = true will get us out of the loop
            valid = true;

        }else {
            System.out.println("Not a positive integer; try again.");
        }

    }
    return posInt;
}
```

This code will reevaluate the input from the beginning if the input before was invalid.
In your code if you enter a negative int you will be prompted to reenter a number.
But since you are already in the `while (posInt <= 0)` loop, it does not recheck if you actually enter a valid input.

The code i provided reevaluates the next input from the beginning until it is found valid.

Comment: @ElizabethFlores if this answer worked best for you, please upvote and mark my answer as the best answer so other people with similar problems can find the solution easier. 
Glad i could help =)

Comment: How do I mark it as the best answer? This was my first post ever on this so I'm a newbie